# non-zero Vector space with new scalar multiplication defined over finite field still vector space?

Tags: linear-algebra, field-theory, finite-fields

If $V$ is a vector space (not the zero vector space) over $\mathbb{R}$, and if $F$ is a finite field.  how could I show that it is not possible to define a new scalar multiplication of $F$ on $V$, in a way that $V$ with this scalar multiplication and the usual addition becomes a vector space over $F$?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I made a mistake in that post in not specifying that I want to see a proof in the case where V is not the 0 vector space.

Comment: It doesn't matter. I've already answered your question.

Comment: ah, I read the first comment and assumed that everyone responded suggesting that it is possible to define such a vector space given the 0 vector.   My apologies